# How to configure the cloud tasks queue programmatically

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

Dev thanks for opening this question and I hope so you can help me to get rid out if the situation.

I am new to the Google cloud service and I am learning the cloud task, I have to create the queue programmatically and add some arguments like processing rate, bucket size. i am not able to find any solution till now.

i am creating the queue in the following way

```
const createQueue = async (
    queueName: string
) => {
    const project = 'projectname'; // Your GCP Project id
    const queue = queueName; // Name of the Queue to create
    const location = 'location name' // The GCP region in which to create the queue
    const {
        v2beta3
    } = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
    const client = new v2beta3.CloudTasksClient();

    try {
        const [response] = await client.createQueue({
            parent: client.locationPath(project, location),
            queue: {
                name: client.queuePath(project, location, queue),
                appEngineHttpQueue: {
                    appEngineRoutingOverride: {
                        service: 'default'
                    }
                },
            },
        });
        console.log(`Created queue ${response.name}`);
        return response.name;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(Error(error.message));
    }
    // return null
}
```

how can I add the arguments like processing rate, bucket size, and the max concurrent rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this property ["rateLimits"](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3#ratelimits) to your "queue" property for example

```
queue: {
   name:client.queuePath(project,location,queue),
   appEngineHttpQueue:{
      appEngineRoutingOverride:{
         service:default
      },
      rateLimits:{
         maxDispatchesPerSecond:500
      },
      retryConfig:{
         maxAttempts:1
      }
   }
```

keep in mind that the property "max_burst_size" is equal to "bucket_size"